# Get last updated date of dll

Tags: c#, .net, date, dll

Is there any way to get the last updated date of all dll of my solution and all dll of my IIS website ?

Just make sure I don't deploy it for nothing if the iis dll last updated dates are later than the dll in the solution.

Comment: if you try to overwrite a file in vista/7/2008 the OS tell you if the newer is older/same date/newer AFAIK

Comment: I always compared the version information of the assembly to information stored in an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"foo.dll");
DateTime result = fi.CreationTime;
```

However, you're probably better off retrieving the [version information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.version.aspx) of your assemblies.